# Unable to bookmark wso2 login url

Tags: saml, wso2

-->User opens Service Provider URL and the WSO2 login screen is presented for entering credentials

-->User does add a browser bookmark from the current page to be able to access it in the future

-->Bookmark works fine for a period of time, then it stops working properly, the following error is displayed after entering the credentials

The reason for the error is that the WSO2 login page has some parameters in the URL that expire after a period of time, specifically sessionDataKey which is identifier for particular Service Provider.

Can someone help resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue and seems to be fixed in next release.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5199

As a workaround, users can bookmark the landing page after the login. Then, if there is no valid session, they will be redirected to the login page.